# VBA Save As saving at document folder

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

My code look's like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub criarplanilha()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    With wb

        .Sheets(1).Name = "Pedidos planejados e estoque"
        .Sheets(2).Name = "Faturado"
        .Sheets(3).Name = "Frontera"

        .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\jmoreira1\Desktop\TestTest"
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

And it works OK. But my question is, why when i change the line

> .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\jmoreira1\Desktop\TestTest"

to

> .SaveAs Filename:="TestTest", Local:="C:\Users\jmoreira1\Desktop"

It save the new workbook file at document folder (C:\Users\jmoreira1\Documents) instead at the desktop.
In my mind both lines should do the same job.

Comment: It appears from the documentation that the `Local` parameter does not take a folder name.  Further, the documentation states for `Filename`:  `A string that indicates the name of the file to be saved. You can include a full path; if you don't, Microsoft Excel saves the file in the current folder.`

Comment: In addition to the above, see the purpose of Local: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas